# Disable edit media attachments?

Tags: attachments

Looking for a way to disable the "Edit Image" option. I would still like to be able to edit the description, alt, etc. But remove the Edit image button or disable that image editor.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Just put this in your functions.php file

```
add_action('admin_head-media-upload-popup', 'remove_edit_image_button'); // for the pop up media box
add_action('admin_head', 'remove_edit_image_button'); // for the media page

function remove_edit_image_button()
{
?>
<style>
    .A1B1 p .button
    {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selectors above didn't work for me; however, after inspecting the page I came up with this, which did work:

```
function remove_edit_image_button()
{
    ?>
    <style>
        .wp_attachment_image p .button
        {
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
<?php
}
```

Could be due to another plugin I'm using, or a different WP version, I don't know.

Just posting in case someone else encounters this.

Comment: This is partial answer. Only hide. User still can build url by hand and edit image.

Answer (score 0):

From [Disable edit option in Media library](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107783/disable-edit-option-in-media-library/107791#107791):

Add some CSS to admin_head to hide the image actions bar, and hide the edit button once clicking into the image:

This should do the trick:

```php
function hide_image_edit_link() {
    echo '<style>
        table.media .row-actions {display:none;}
        .wp_attachment_image input[id^="imgedit-open-btn"] {display:none;}
    </style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_image_edit_link');
```