# Disable edit option in Media library

Tags: media, library

Hovering my mouse over a file name or a thumbnail brings up the Edit option, I want to know is there any hook to disable all edit links in Media library on Multisite
[image]

Comment: What is your context for requirement? Should items be _absolutely_ uneditable? Only for specific users or other conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're several filters that you can utilize:

### Custom column content

If you got a custom column that you added with the ``-filter, then you can use the

```
manage_{$post->post_type}_posts_custom_column
```

filter to alter the content. If you only want to target non-hierarchial post types then there's as well the `manage_posts_custom_column` and for hierarchical ones, there's `manage_pages_custom_column`. All three filters have two arguemnts: `$column_name, $post->ID`.

For the media library there's a special filter: `manage_media_custom_column`.

### Removing actions

IIRC, there's the following filter to add or remove different actions:

```
apply_filters( 'bulk_actions-' . $this->screen->id, $this->_actions );
```

You should be able to obtain the screen ID from `get_current_screen()->ID`.

For the media library it's - again - a special case and you have to use the

```
apply_filters( 'media_row_actions', $actions, $post, $this->detached );
```

filter.

Make sure that you don't use `$this->` inside your callback arguments as you're not in object context.

### Removing the image link

So far there's no possibility to completely remove the `<a href="" ...` tag without a lot of effort. **But** you can (simply) set the link target to the current page with using the `get_edit_post_link`-filter.

Just re-target it to `sprintf( '#post-%s', $post_id );`:

```
add_filter( 'get_edit_post_link', 'wpse107783_remove_media_icon_link', 20, 2 );
function wpse107783_remove_media_icon_link( $url, $post_id )
{
    if ( 'upload' !== get_current_screen()->id )
        return $url;

    return sprintf( '#post-%s', $post_id );
}
```

### Why not CSS or JS?

Still people could remove event listeners or CSS rules via their developer tools, which is something you might not want.

### Redirect

A *real* lock out can only happen server side based on roles and capabilities.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse107783_redirect_media_edit' );
function wpse107783_redirect_media_edit()
{
    if (
        ! is_admin()
        OR 'attachment' !== get_current_screen()->id
    )
        return;

    exit( wp_redirect( admin_url() ) );
}
```

*Note: I'm not sure if `template_redirect` is the right hook here. It might as well be `admin_menu` or `init`.*

Answer (score 3):

Add some CSS to admin_head to hide the image actions bar, and hide the edit button once clicking into the image:

This should do the trick:

```php
function hide_image_edit_link() {
    echo '<style>
        table.media .row-actions {display:none;}
        .wp_attachment_image input[id^="imgedit-open-btn"] {display:none;}
    </style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_image_edit_link');
```

Comment: I can still edit files clicking on a file name or a thumbnail

Comment: This wasn't clear from your question. 

Code updated, to also hide the button when clicking into the image, I presume you don't want to disable this entirely.